# How to use MVVM Light DialogMessage In Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am trying to get the DialogMessage with Windows Phone 7 but I can only find examples for sliverlight which don't seem to work for me.

I put this code in my Constructor of my ViewModel

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="DialogMessageMvvM.MainPage"
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                            xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                            xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
                            mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                            SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
                            Orientation="Portrait"
                            d:DesignWidth="480"
                            d:DesignHeight="768"
                            shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
                            DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <!--LayoutRoot contains the root grid where all other page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Margin="24,24,0,12">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle"
                       Text="{Binding ApplicationTitle}"
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle"
                       Text="{Binding PageName}"
                       Margin="-3,-8,0,0"
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"
              Grid.Row="1">

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WelcomeTitle}"
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="40" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       TextAlignment="Center" />

        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="appbar_button1" IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"></shell:ApplicationBarIconButton>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="appbar_button2" IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"></shell:ApplicationBarIconButton>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuItem1" Text="MenuItem 1"></shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuItem2" Text="MenuItem 2"></shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    -->


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        Messenger.Default.Register<DialogMessage>(
       this,
       msg =>
       {
           var result = MessageBox.Show(
               msg.Content,
               msg.Caption,
               msg.Button);

           // Send callback
           msg.ProcessCallback(result);
       });

    }
}
```

MainViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private const string Login = "abcd1234";

        public RelayCommand<string> CheckLoginCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="Message" /> property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string MessagePropertyName = "Message";

        private string _message = "Login";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Message property.
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// </summary>
        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return _message;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_message == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _message = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(MessagePropertyName);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            CheckLoginCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(CheckLogin);
        }

        private void CheckLogin(string text)
        {
            if (text == Login)
            {
                var message = new DialogMessage("Login confirmed, do you want to continue", DialogMessageCallback)
                {
                    Button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,
                    Caption = "Continue?"
                };

                Messenger.Default.Send(message);
            }
        }

        private void DialogMessageCallback(MessageBoxResult result)
        {
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                Message = "Continue";
            }
            else
            {
                Message = "Stop";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown when your view model is created but I'd guess that it's before you've registered the listener.

Comment: I just register the VM in the ViewModel Location? Should I be registering the Dialog Message?

Comment: @chobo2  Yes, you may have registered it there but when is it being constructed? To test if this is the issue set a break point on the send and the receive and see what order they're hit in.

Comment: Seems like first ViewModel is hit and then the CodeBehind page is hit. Do you think you could write up an example of all the code I need or something?

Comment: @chobo2 can you provide a minimal repro? The issue is probably that your VM for the page is defined in XAML and is constructed as part of page construction and triggered by the call to `InitializeComponent`. You may be able to work around the issue by registering the listener first but page and viewmodel reuse may cause further issues down the line. You'll be better served by understanding your viewmodel lifecycles.

Comment: You seem to be right it has to come before the InitalizeComponent. I am using the MVVMLight template and that is how the VM is defined in the XAML. I then followed the Example I found for silverlight that had it after the InitalizeComponent.

Comment: Also what happens if I want to use the XNA message box for more custom options? Is that easy to do?